# How to download gz file from S3 to API Gateway

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, gzip

I am trying to download gz file from S3 bucket through API Gateway.

I have tried convert if binary on response integration, but returned data is a garbage from the API Gateway endpoint.

How can I get the configuration?

Comment: Q: Have you looked here (REST API examples): https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-s3.html?  These examples can be run from [curl](https://curl.se/download.html), [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), etc.: just provide the correct URL and authentication in your request.

Comment: The response is coming as a json response, not as binary.  {
  "image": "W3JhdyBieXRlc10="
} . Anyway to get the resulting file streamed as binary response instead of application/json.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for pointing that out. WIll test it out.